# Overriding an enum in Java

Tags: java, enums, overriding

I have a *class* in Java which has an *enum* implementing an *interface* such as

```
class MyClass{
interface Command{
    void execute();
    String getId();
}

enum MyCommands implements Command{
    aCmd{
        void execute(){/*do something*/}
        String getId(){return "aCmd";}
    }
}

void MyMethod(String s){
    for(Command cmd: MyCommands){
        if(s.equals(cmd.getId())) cmd.execute();
    }
}
}
```

The class has a method for parsing text, in which I iterate over the *enum* values and compare the input to the *getId()* of each command.

Now I do want to extend the class with different commands (that is, I want to extend it in a way that overrides MyCommands and defines new commands). How can I do that?
(I'm open to refactoring the super class in other simple way)

```
class childClass extends myClass{
    //In myMethod this enum should be iterated instead of myCommands
    enum childCommands implements Command{
        otherCmd{
        void execute(){/*do something*/}
        String getId(){return "aCmd";}
        }
}
```

Comment: If by `"extend the class"` you mean create a new enum that extends this one, then you can't do that.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I mean, I want to create a new class which extends my class whose behaviour is exactly the same but has different commands.

Comment: Why? What's the design behind this requirement?

Comment: what do you mean by "extend the class with different commands"? Can you show your final goal please? Also the code you posted cannot possibly compile. Would be nice if you fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extend your class it is probably better to create an additional `enum` e.g. `MyExtendedCommands`. Then you can create a `Set<Command>` in that class that contains both the original `EnumSet` and the extended `EnumSet` of both `MyCommands` and `MyExtendedCommands`.

```
class MyClass {
    interface Command {
        void execute();

        String getId();
    }

    enum MyCommands implements Command {

        aCmd {
            public void execute() {/* do something */
            }

            public String getId() {
                return "aCmd";
            }
        }
    }

    public void myMethod(String s) {
        for (Command cmd : EnumSet.allOf(MyCommands.class)) {
            if (s.equals(cmd.getId()))
                cmd.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

can be extended by using:

```
class MyExtendedClass extends MyClass {

    enum MyExtendedCommands implements Command {

        bCmd {
            public void execute() {/* do something */
            }

            public String getId() {
                return name();
            }
        }
    }

    public void myMethod(String s){
        Set<Command> allCommands = new HashSet<>();
        allCommands.addAll(EnumSet.allOf(MyCommands.class));
        allCommands.addAll(EnumSet.allOf(MyExtendedCommands.class));

        for(Command cmd: allCommands){
            if(s.equals(cmd.getId())) cmd.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't protect you against duplicates at compile time. But it should be easy to prevent dupes at runtime (e.g. by testing the number of resulting commands in `allCommands`.

Then again, this is an easy method to override commands as well, so maybe this drawback can be turned into an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Add the `public` key word and `@Override` them.

```
interface Command{
    void execute();
    String getId();
}

enum MyCommands implements Command{
    aCmd{
        @Override
        public void execute() { 
            /*do something*/ 
        }

        @Override
        public String getId() { 
            return "aCmd"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover you have few mistakes such as:

- `String` with the small `s` in the beggining
- Missing `;` in `return "aCmd"`

Comment: NikolasCharalambidis I must agree with @MaartenBodewes. Sorry if the question was unclear.

Comment: I'll remind myself to indicate what *was* asked directly instead of the non-constructive "that wasn't asked". So let's try again: This answer doesn't extend the class with additional commands as indicated in the question: "Now I do want to extend the class with different commands". Hope that's OK.

Comment: Fine, not a problem. I see I got the OP wrong. Thank you for comments.